# Shopify webhook return me nothing?

Tags: reactjs, shopify, webhooks, koa

I'm trying to get the webhook data with a webhook created with WEBHOOK API https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/events/webhooksubscription

here is my code

```
server.use(graphQLProxy({ version: ApiVersion.Unstable }));

router.post('/webhooks/products/update', verifyRequest(), async (ctx) => {
    console.log('received webhook: ', ctx); // output nothing ?
  
  });

  server.use(router.allowedMethods());
  server.use(router.routes());
```

and my server return me correctly the post request

```
POST /webhooks/products/update                                  302 Found
```

But nothing in output ? any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The middleware you are using is not for the webhooks.

`verifyRequest()` is slightly different from the webhook middleware.

You need to set the proper middleware there:

```
import {receiveWebhook} from '@shopify/koa-shopify-webhooks';

const webhook = receiveWebhook({secret: SHOPIFY_SECRET});

router.post('/webhooks/products/update', webhook, () => {
  /* handle products update */
});
```

Docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/koa-shopify-webhooks?activeTab=readme

Comment: so how should i do by using the api ? i got an POST /webhooks/products/update                                            403 Forbidden when using receiveWebhook

Comment: @totobolocolo how are you handling the post body? For webhooks for me `koa-body` had problems and I used `koa-bodyparser-graphql` for them, and `koa-body` for everything else. `server.use(async (ctx, next) => ctx.path.includes('/webhooks') ? await bodyparser()(ctx, next) : await koaBody()(ctx, next));`